# how to use link_to with post method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

i have a url which searches the transactions and gives the result back. It is a post call. The url is "http://192.168.58.129:3000/search". i have a column called token which has values and i have implemented link_to for each value. On clicking token value, it should search based on the token. Currently, it is behaving like get call, appending all params to url. I want it to behave like post with the same url(http://192.168.58.129:3000/search) with params appended to form-data and not url.

`

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="search-result-table" style="margin-left:2%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Transaction Id</th>
          <th>Order Id</th>
          <th>Store Id</th>
          <th>Transaction Date</th>
          <th>Transaction Type</th>
          <th>Tender Type</th>
          <th>Token</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Currency</th>
          <th>Response </br>Code</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <% @transactions.each do |transaction| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= link_to transaction['payment_transaction_id'], details_path(payment_transaction_id: transaction['payment_transaction_id']), {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'} %></td>
            <td><%= transaction['payment_session_id'] %></td>
            <td><%= transaction['store_id'] %></td>
            <td><%= transaction['create_timestamp'].in_time_zone(@timezone).strftime('%B %d, %Y - %l:%M %p') %></td>
            <td><%= @transaction_types[transaction['transaction_type']] %></td>
            <td><%= @tenders[transaction['tender_type']][1] %></td>
            <% if (@tenders[transaction['tender_type']][0]).in?(['PLCC', 'GC', 'CC', 'CBCC']) %>
              <td><%= link_to transaction['payment_acct_unique_id'], params.merge(account_id: transaction['payment_acct_unique_id'], show_results: "true",clickAccount:"Y"), id: "act_id" %></td>
            <% else %>
              <td><%= transaction['payment_acct_unique_id'] %></td>
            <% end %>
            <% if show_settlement_type? %>
              <td><%= PaymentsHelper.settlement_amount_with_currency_symbol transaction['transaction_amount'], transaction['iso_currency_code'],transaction['settlement_type'] %></td>
            <% else %>
              <td><%= PaymentsHelper.amount_with_currency_symbol transaction['transaction_amount'], transaction['iso_currency_code'] %></td>
            <% end %>
            <td><%= transaction['iso_currency_code'] %></td>
            <% if transaction['transaction_status'] == ('F') %>
              <td>Payment Service Error</td>
            <% else %>
              <td><%= transaction['response_code'] %></td>
            <% end %>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

`

Comment: use `method: post` in `link_to`

Answer (score 0):

link button

here token_id become view button label.

```
  <%= link_to "token_id",transactions_path%>
```

transactions_path method,its a link for index page for  different page they is a
  different method

EX :

```
   HTTP Verb       Path             Controller#Action   Used for

    1 = GET       /photos            photos#index       display a list of all photos
    2 = GET       /photos/new        photos#new         return an HTML form for creating a new 
        photo
    3 = POST      /photos             photos#create     create a new photo
    4 = GET       /photos/:id         photos#show       display a specific photo
    5 = GET       /photos/:id/edit    photos#edit       return an HTML form for editing a 
        photo
    6 = PATCH/PUT /photos/:id         photos#update     update a specific photo
    7 = DELETE    /photos/:id         photos#destroy    delete a specific photo
```

Path EX methods: for different actions

```
   index    articles_path
   new      new_article_path
   show     article_path(:id)
   edit     edit_article_path(:id)
   update   article_path(:id)
   destroy  article_path(:id)
```

Comment: Thank You..I tried that way, still its getting appended to url.